# Perl XML::LibXML - read the nodevalue from an element if nodevalue of it's parent element matches a string

Tags: python, xml, xml-libxml

I am using Perl XML::LibXML for extracting some data from an XML like below one.

The XML:

```
<root>
<child1>
    <child2>
        <common_tag_name>
            <name>name_level1_name1</name>
            <attribute>
              <name>name_level2_name1</name>
              <value>some_data1</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <name>name_level2_name2</name>
              <value>some_data2</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <name>name_level2_name3</name>
              <value>some_data3</value>
            </attribute>
        </common_tag_name>

        <common_tag_name>
            <name>name_level1_name2</name>
            <attribute>
              <name>name_level2_name1</name>
              <value>some_data4</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <name>name_level2_name2</name>
              <value>some_data5</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <name>name_level2_name3</name>
              <value>some_data6</value>
            </attribute>
        </common_tag_name>
    </child2>
</child1>
</root>
```

Problem:

Find ; if /common_tag_name/name == "name_level1_name1" and /common_tag_name/name/attribute/name == "name_level2_name1" then extract /common_tag_name/name/attribute/value    i.e. I should get "some_data1"

Should loop this to read same_data*

Is it possible with XML::LibXML?

Comment: You say Perl in the title but tagged with Python. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible to do that with [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML).